# looping through files older than 2 hours in bash

Tags: bash, shell, ftp

I have a small script that I would loop through an ftp and if it finds a file older than lets say 2 hours it will execute a command, this loop also has another condition which I dont need help on. I only need help on finding files older than n minutes. This is what I have

```
for file in $(ls); do

if [ $file is older than 2 hours ] && [ another condition   ]; then
        #execute a command
fi

done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an easy workaround:

```
find $(ls) -amin +120 -exec some command here \;
```

I use this to process files from an FTP server that are older than a few minutes so I don't read partial files.

You can "man find" for other options, as amin is accessed longer than n minutes ago, there is also mmin for modified more than n minutes ago, and many, many, many other options.

Note: to reference the found file's path in your -exec, substitute with {}

for example, if you want to append a file with .found:

```
find /tmp/targets/ -amin 120 -exec mv {} {}.found \;
```

That will rename all files in /tmp/targets/ with their name appended with .found at the end. Note that the \; is for escaping the -exec command. If you just use ; then the -exec won't be closed and you will get an error. you can string multiple commands using ; before closing escape with \;

Comment: `$(ls)` is both unnecessary and error prone if there are file/folders whose names contain spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your other condition is, but a very easy way to find files by a certain age is

```
find . -mmin +120 | xargs your_command
```

Comment: if the other condition is to find a file with a certain extension?

Comment: @user3768541 "this loop also has another condition which I dont need help on. I only need help on finding files older than n minutes." If you need an other condition please edit your question to explain it. In the meantime, take a look a the documentation of the `find` command: it allows multiple (and very complex) conditions ;)